# How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL Server with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table like this

| RowID | Model | Request No | Resource | Date | Time | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | W221A0 | RE-1716 | RG | 14-Jan-22 | 9:50:40 | 4 |
| 14 | X210132 | RE-1341 | CL | 15-Dec-21 | 10:45:09 | 2 |
| 20 | X210132 | RE-1341 | ZA | 17-Dec-21 | 8:57:09 | 5 |
| 30 | X210132 | RE-1341 | SA | 21-Dec-21 | 8:10:02 | 1 |
| 44 | W221A0 | RE-1716 | RG | 10-Jan-22 | 10:14:40 | 8 |
| 59 | X210132 | RE-1341 | ZA | 16-Dec-21 | 9:56:46 | 3 |
| 60 | X210132 | RE-1341 | SA | 20-Dec-21 | 8:30:50 | 0 |
| 95 | X210132 | RE-1341 | ZA | 21-Dec-21 | 10:12:51 | 6 |
| 99 | W221A0 | RE-1716 | RG | 11-Jan-22 | 8:06:46 | 2 |
| 100 | X210132 | RE-1341 | ZA | 15-Dec-21 | 10:20:26 | 12 |
| 102 | W221A0 | RE-1716 | CL | 14-Jan-22 | 8:10:27 | 3 |
| 105 | W221A0 | RE-1716 | TE | 10-Jan-22 | 8:36:33 | 7 |
| 106 | W221A0 | RE-1716 | RG | 6-Jan-22 | 10:29:44 | 5 |
| 300 | W221A0 | RE-1716 | RG | 14-Jan-22 | 9:01:18 | 6 |

After sorting by Date, Time field. I expect to have new table with Like this:

[image: like this]

The sequence of the table is important to determine the grouping by `Resource` value, the `Resources` that are sequentially next to each other should be collapsed together to build the `STEP` and `STEP TIME`, where the `STEP TIME` value for each resource is the `SUM` of the `Duration` values for that `Resource`.

These two images should illustrate how the computed values are constructed:

[image: Step]
[image: Step Time]

I tried use

```
     SELECT Main.[Request No.],LEFT(Main.STORAGEDATA,Len(Main.STORAGEDATA)-1) As "Process" FROM(
    
      SELECT DISTINCT ST2.[Request No.], 
        (
            SELECT ST1.Resource + ',' AS [text()]
            FROM dbo.STORAGEDATA ST1
            WHERE ST1.[Request No.] = ST2.[Request No.]
            ORDER BY ST1.[Request No.]
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
        ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') STORAGEDATA
    FROM dbo.STORAGEDATA ST2
) [Main]
```

However, It doesn't return what I expect, this is the output:

| Request No. | Process |
| --- | --- |
| RE-1341 | CL,ZA,SA,ZA,SA,ZA,ZA |
| RE-1716 | RG,RG,RG,CL,TE,RG,RG |

---

This `CREATE TABLE` expression can be used for this dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE STORAGEDATA (
    RowID int,
    Model varchar(10),
    [Request No.] varchar(10),
    [Resource] char(2),
    [Date] Date,
    [Time] Time,
    Duration int
    )
INSERT INTO STORAGEDATA
VALUES
 ( 12   ,'W221A0 ','RE-1716','RG','14-Jan-22','9:50:40  ',4  )
,( 14   ,'X210132','RE-1341','CL','15-Dec-21','10:45:09 ',2  )
,( 20   ,'X210132','RE-1341','ZA','17-Dec-21','8:57:09  ',5  )
,( 30   ,'X210132','RE-1341','SA','21-Dec-21','8:10:02  ',1  )
,( 44   ,'W221A0 ','RE-1716','RG','10-Jan-22','10:14:40 ',8  )
,( 59   ,'X210132','RE-1341','ZA','16-Dec-21','9:56:46  ',3  )
,( 60   ,'X210132','RE-1341','SA','20-Dec-21','8:30:50  ',0  )
,( 95   ,'X210132','RE-1341','ZA','21-Dec-21','10:12:51 ',6  )
,( 99   ,'W221A0 ','RE-1716','RG','11-Jan-22','8:06:46  ',2  )
,( 100  ,'X210132','RE-1341','ZA','15-Dec-21','10:20:26 ',12 )
,( 102  ,'W221A0 ','RE-1716','CL','14-Jan-22','8:10:27  ',3  )
,( 105  ,'W221A0 ','RE-1716','TE','10-Jan-22','8:36:33  ',7  )
,( 106  ,'W221A0 ','RE-1716','RG','6-Jan-22 ','10:29:44 ',5  )
,( 300  ,'W221A0 ','RE-1716','RG','14-Jan-22','9:01:18  ',6  );
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need this but check this out STRING_AGG https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Its not immediately clear, but this is a _Gap and Island_ Issue, where the `Resource` values determine the islands. Its an interesting one, take me a few minutes...

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses Gap and Island analysis to identify the main resource grouping, by then uses `STRING_AGG` to generate the `Step` and `Step Time` columns and then joins those results back onto the original set.

```
;WITH LagData as (
    SELECT *, LAG(Resource,1) OVER(PARTITION BY Model, [Request No.] ORDER BY Date,Time) LG
    FROM STORAGEDATA ST2
), IslandIds as (
    SELECT *, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN LG IS NULL OR Resource <> LG THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  OVER(PARTITION BY [Request No.] ORDER BY Date,TIme) IslandId
    FROM LagData
), Islands as (
  SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT Model, [Resource], IslandId, SUM(Duration) as TotalDuration 
  FROM IslandIds 
  GROUP BY IslandId, Model, [Resource]
  ORDER BY IslandId
)
, ModelSummary as (
    SELECT Model
          ,STRING_AGG([Resource], '*') as Step
          ,STRING_AGG(TotalDuration, ',') as [Step Time]
      FROM Islands 
      GROUP BY Model
)
SELECT main.Model,main.[Request No.],main.[Resource],main.[Date],main.[Time],main.Duration
     , ModelSummary.Step
     , ModelSummary.[Step Time]
FROM IslandIds as main
INNER JOIN ModelSummary ON ModelSummary.Model = main.Model
ORDER BY main.Model DESC, [Date], [Time]
```

> **NOTE:** Special acknowledgement to the [solution by @JMabee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70741997/1690217), this solution was edited to use the simple *Island only* analysis, as we are not analysing the gaps here.
>
> This solution is still different in the way the string aggregation is evaluated.

The `TOP 100 PERCENT` is a bit of a hack to ensure the correct sequence for the `STRING_AGG`

The setup I used for this was:

```
CREATE TABLE STORAGEDATA (
    RowID int,
    Model varchar(10),
    [Request No.] varchar(10),
    [Resource] char(2),
    [Date] Date,
    [Time] Time,
    Duration int
    )
INSERT INTO STORAGEDATA
VALUES
 ( 12   ,'W221A0 ','RE-1716','RG','14-Jan-22','9:50:40  ',4  )
,( 14   ,'X210132','RE-1341','CL','15-Dec-21','10:45:09 ',2  )
,( 20   ,'X210132','RE-1341','ZA','17-Dec-21','8:57:09  ',5  )
,( 30   ,'X210132','RE-1341','SA','21-Dec-21','8:10:02  ',1  )
,( 44   ,'W221A0 ','RE-1716','RG','10-Jan-22','10:14:40 ',8  )
,( 59   ,'X210132','RE-1341','ZA','16-Dec-21','9:56:46  ',3  )
,( 60   ,'X210132','RE-1341','SA','20-Dec-21','8:30:50  ',0  )
,( 95   ,'X210132','RE-1341','ZA','21-Dec-21','10:12:51 ',6  )
,( 99   ,'W221A0 ','RE-1716','RG','11-Jan-22','8:06:46  ',2  )
,( 100  ,'X210132','RE-1341','ZA','15-Dec-21','10:20:26 ',12 )
,( 102  ,'W221A0 ','RE-1716','CL','14-Jan-22','8:10:27  ',3  )
,( 105  ,'W221A0 ','RE-1716','TE','10-Jan-22','8:36:33  ',7  )
,( 106  ,'W221A0 ','RE-1716','RG','6-Jan-22 ','10:29:44 ',5  )
,( 300  ,'W221A0 ','RE-1716','RG','14-Jan-22','9:01:18  ',6  );
```

Comment: It seems `STRING_AGG` is not supported in MS SQL Server 2014 That I'm using. Do you have any solution for it ? Thank you

Comment: The natural first question is why are you still stuck on 2014... but otherwise the answer by [@JMabee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70741997/1690217) should work in 2014

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it, I am definitely interested to see how other folks solve this one. It appears to be a Gaps and Islands problem, so the CTEs are used to create a Group using the Resource within the Request No.

The second part uses subqueries to generate the distinct Resource and also the SUM of the duration within the Group as lists.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(RowID int,Model varchar(10), [Request No.] varchar(10),[Resource] varchar(10), [Date] Date, [Time] Time, Duration int );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES
( 12 ,'W221A0' ,'RE-1716','RG','14-Jan-22','9:50:40' ,4),
( 14 ,'X210132','RE-1341','CL','15-Dec-21','10:45:09',2),
( 20 ,'X210132','RE-1341','ZA','17-Dec-21','8:57:09' ,5),
( 30 ,'X210132','RE-1341','SA','21-Dec-21','8:10:02' ,1),
( 44 ,'W221A0' ,'RE-1716','RG','10-Jan-22','10:14:40',8),
( 59 ,'X210132','RE-1341','ZA','16-Dec-21','9:56:46' ,3),
( 60 ,'X210132','RE-1341','SA','20-Dec-21','8:30:50' ,0),
( 95 ,'X210132','RE-1341','ZA','21-Dec-21','10:12:51',6),
( 99 ,'W221A0' ,'RE-1716','RG','11-Jan-22','8:06:46' ,2),
( 100,'X210132','RE-1341','ZA','15-Dec-21','10:20:26',12),
( 102,'W221A0' ,'RE-1716','CL','14-Jan-22','8:10:27' ,3),
( 105,'W221A0' ,'RE-1716','TE','10-Jan-22','8:36:33' ,7),
( 106,'W221A0' ,'RE-1716','RG','6-Jan-22 ','10:29:44',5),
( 300,'W221A0' ,'RE-1716','RG','14-Jan-22','9:01:18' ,6);

WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *, LAG(Resource,1) OVER(PARTITION BY [Request No.] ORDER BY Date,Time) LG
FROM #tmp ST2
),CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT *, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN LG IS NULL OR Resource <> LG THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  OVER(PARTITION BY [Request No.] ORDER BY Date,TIme) GRP
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT RowID, Model,[Request No.], Resource,[Date],[Time],Duration,
        STUFF((SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES '*' + ST1.Resource AS [text()]
            FROM CTE2 ST1
            WHERE ST1.[Request No.] = ST2.[Request No.]
            ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GRP ORDER BY  Date,Time)
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
        ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') Step,

        STUFF((SELECT  '-' + CAST(SUM(Duration)  as varchar(5))  AS [text()]
            FROM CTE2 ST1
            WHERE ST1.[Request No.] = ST2.[Request No.]
            GROUP BY Grp
            ORDER BY GRP
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
        ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') StepTime
FROM CTE2 ST2
ORDER BY Date, Time
```